# How can I use my class properties in my Linq query with group by statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to use my entity class properties in my linq query that return some value with it.

so this my linq query;

```
List<PvmBarChartData> BaseofSegmentIPPGMR = (from si in db.ScoreItem
 join s in db.Score on si.ScoreId equals s.Id
 join prg in db.ProjectResearchGroup on si.ProjectResearchGroupId equals prg.Id
 join rg in db.RgClone on prg.RgCloneId equals rg.Id
 join sp in db.SalesPoint on s.SalesPointId equals sp.Id
 join c in db.Channel on sp.ChannelId equals c.Id
 where (si.ResearchGroupType == ResearchGroupType.ScoreCard && spIds.Contains(s.SalesPointId))
 group si by c.Name into g
 select new PvmBarChartData
 {
    GroupName = g.Key,

    DataValues = new List<CvmNameValuePair>{ new CvmNameValuePair{

    Name = "",
    Value = g.Average(x => x.TotalScore)
 }
}
})
.ToList();
```

so for instance I would like to set Name properties with my entity framework model class' properties' value, Name = s.Name,

How can I implement this on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way that you can access s.Name is by doing another linq query on g, since g is now a data set of grouped objects.

```
Name = (from gx in g select gx.Name).FirstorDefault();
```